# Firebase Deploy Functions - Failed to update function - Firebase Admin this.appStore?.removeApp(this.name);

Tags: firebase

Upgrading `firebase-functions` from 3.x to 4.x and `firebase-admin` 9.x to 11.x and the deploys aren't working anymore

On deploy this error is received:

```
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function
```

And within log explorer there's

```
Provided module can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-app.js:174
        this.appStore?.removeApp(this.name);
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/lifecycle.js:25:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

I've updated the package.json to have the following for node engine and it's still having an issue w/ deploying

```
"engine" 16
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple more requirements if I follow the documentation.

Previous:

```
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
export const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});
```

New Fix:

```
import { applicationDefault, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
export const app = initializeApp({
  credential: applicationDefault(),
});
```